# How to encode ordinal data before applying linear regression in STATA?

Tags: linear-regression, encoding, stata

I have a data set that has student performance marks (continuous and dependent variable), Teacher Qualification (Ordinal and independent variable containing categories: Masters, Bachelors, High School). I want to apply the regression analysis to check the impact of teacher qualification on student's marks.

How can I encode ordinal data before applying linear regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to dummy-encode teacher qualification. So each level of qualification enters the regression with a separate intercept term. Note that dummy-encoding always works against a contrast level. So when "Master degree" is the base-level, you will see the effect of "Bachelor" compared to "Master" etc.

You can dummy-encode in Stata by using the `i.` prefix, e.g. `summarize i.size`. In a regression you would use `reg y i.x`.

See the [Stata docs](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-dummy-variables/) for details.